# Yii2 return $this->goBack() Not Working

Tags: redirect, yii2, return

I am facing the problem with return to previous page, will be very thankful if some help me.
This is my controller login action

```
    public function actionLogin() {
        $this->layout = 'login';
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
}
```

when i enter the username and password every things goes right but the user stay in same page(login page.). I also try to render some other view or redirect it to some action but its not working.
When i echo something before goBack() function its working fine which means user is login.

Comment: Have a look at the doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#goBack()-detail The URL needs to be set before to let `goBack()` know where to go to.

Comment: can you please tell in which file and how to set returnUrl???

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);


return $this->goBack((
        !empty(Yii::$app->request->referrer) ? Yii::$app->request->referrer : null
));
```

or

```
if(Yii::$app->request->referrer){
    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}else{
  return $this->goHome();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remember each called action after the action was executed. This can be done with [`setReturnUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#setReturnUrl()-detail) at the user object (note: the user object is also present for an anonymous user). If this is done [`goBack()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#goBack()-detail) works as expected.

The place where you call `setReturnUrl()` is in the [afterAction event](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#afterAction). You can implement this in the application configuration (e.g. web.php). It looks like this:

```
$config = [
    'id'              => 'foo-app',
    'basePath'        => dirname(__DIR__),
    'params'          => ...
    'bootstrap'       => ['log'],
    'components'      => ...,

    'on afterAction' => function (yii\base\ActionEvent $e) {
        if($e->action->id !== 'login' && $e->action->controller->id !== 'site')
            Yii::$app->user->setReturnUrl(Yii::$app->request->url);
    },
];
```

`'on afterAction'` is called each time an action was called. In [`Yii::$app->request->url`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$url-detail) contains the last (currently) called full URL.

I have added the if-statement so that the URL with site/login won't be stored, since this is not a page that you want to go back to.

I have not tested this. I hope it works. According to [this discussion](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4343) using [Yii::$app->request->referrer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$referrer-detail) is not reliable.

Found also some information [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/6876734-problems-with-the-method-goback).

Comment: still having the same issue

Comment: @Dani Do you have some other special things? An AccessControl implementation/usage or an derived User class? The default login process in yii2-app-advanced or yii2-app-basic should already have the desired behaviour out of the box, as far as I know. And how is site/login gets called?

Comment: sory for my late rply i have implement the login system from yii2 improved version. I still having the same issue please help me its so urgent thanks

Comment: @Dani Which improved version? Without any further information I cannot help you.

Comment: this does not work correctly if used inside the `config` as `on beforeAction` event , if i am on a page say `lead/index` and click logout and on login again it wont take me to that page but  it adds the `debug/default/toolbar?tag=5b8d0c22544a8` as the return url and redirects to that page after login, any idea what could be wrong here, i have the `YII_DEBUG=>true`

Comment: you should add the debug controller to exception list too otherwise in debug mode it will always redirect you to the debug tool bar controller, changing `if($e->action->id !== 'login' && $e->action->controller->id !== 'site')` to `if ($e->action->id !== 'login' && !in_array($e->action->controller->id, ['site', 'debug'])) {` will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You Need To assign your User/login model in Config 
Open web.php and add your login/User model
for example.

```
 'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Users',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
```